# Patch not picking up updates

Tags: powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas, patching

I have a multi-screen app that connects to a SharePoint list which works pretty well when a new item is being created but when I am trying to update an item, my patch function does not pick up the changes in my forms.

My initial screen lets the user pick a request type, depending on the request type, it navigates to that screen.

[image: Main Screen]

Each form has the following code for the property Item:

```
If(IsBlank(SharePointIntegration.Selected),varFormData,SharePointIntegration.Selected)
```

[image: GenericForm Screen]

Each form has a Submit button that has this code for the OnSelect property:

```
Patch(
         'Tracker',
          varFormData,
          GenericForm.Updates
);

If(
          IsEmpty(Errors('Sales Operations Tracker')),
          Notify(
                "Success",
                NotificationType.Success
          );
         Navigate(MainScreen),
         Notify(
                First(Errors('Sales Operations Tracker')).Message,
                NotificationType.Error
                   )
)
```

It works pretty good if I am creating a new list item but if I am updating a list item, it doesn't pick up the changes. Is something wrong with the way I coded my patch function?

Hoping to get some insights on here! Thanks!

Comment: What is stored in the `varFormData`? Is it updating the date in backend data source or updating the data locally within app?

Comment: Pass the original record (not `varFormData`) as the second argument to the Patch function. `Patch('Tracker',SharePointIntegration.Selected,GenericForm.Updates);` Here `SharePointIntegration.Selected` is the original record that you want to update, and `GenericForm.Updates` contains the changes.